# iphone app only works first time on simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I've got an issue with my iphone App and i'm not sure if its an xcode project issue or a code issue (I'm leaning towards xcode project issue at the moment).

If I reset the iphone simulator and build and run my app it works fine. If I then do a build and debug again the app will crash straight away with no meaningful callstack. The app will continue to crash until I remove it and start again. I didn't previously have this issue which makes me think i've just changed some project setting recently by mistake.

Has anyone had this before or can anyone think or a reason for this issue?

Comment: you need to provide some more details... may be the crash log?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving/retrieving state? Without any other details, that's the first area I'd look into. Also try setting breakpoints and debug to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

paul_sns is correct, try setting breakpoint on your AppDelegate class and step-over. Probably you're retreaving a state that is incorrect. You could also activate the debugging console (run the application in debug mode) to see where it crashes (the callstack).

Answer (score 0):

OK I've finally got to the bottom of it. I had quite a lot of memory overwriting going on (a sizing issue with a 2d array) and this was why it wasn't giving me any useful information when it crashed. Thanks for all the help - am glad I stumbled upon the problem before I pulled all my hair out!